# Change ScrollView position when viewDidLoad

Tags: ios, swift3, uiscrollview

I new to using ScrollViews. I'm wondering if some can help me. I have a scrollView that looks like this.

[image]

This is how it looks when it loads in the simulator.

[image]

Okay now what I'm trying to do is change the x position of the scrollView when the viewDidLoad. When it loads I would like to make the blue view show on the right side and not the red view on the left side. So it would look something like this when the viewDidLoad.

[image]

So how would I be able to change the scrollView x.position so when it loads the scrollView position is all the way to the right side instead of the left side. So I would have to scroll left to reach the red view. Would really appreciate any help or any really good tutorials on changing scrollView positions. Thanks :)

How my code looks like.

```
class HeroDetailVC: UIViewController {

//MARK: - Outlets
@IBOutlet weak var heroBackgroundImageView: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var heroBackgroundScrollView: UIScrollView!
@IBOutlet weak var mainScrollView: UIScrollView!


//MARK: - Properties
override var prefersStatusBarHidden: Bool { return true }
var heroBackgroundImageWidth: CGFloat = 0



override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    heroBackgroundImageWidth = heroBackgroundImageView.frame.size.width
    adjustHeroBackgroundImage()
}

override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    adjustHeroBackgroundImage()
}


func adjustHeroBackgroundImage() {

    let screenSize = UIScreen.main.bounds.size
    let leftInset = screenSize.width - heroBackgroundImageWidth

    if leftInset < 0 {
        heroBackgroundScrollView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: leftInset, bottom: 0, right: 0)
    } else {
        heroBackgroundScrollView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0)
    }
}
```

Comment: scrollView.contentOffset = CGPointMake(x,y); try using this in viewDidLoad

Comment: are you using auto-layout ? What's is your code you are trying moving it ?

Comment: Thanks elk_cloner and GIJOW for taking the time to reply to my question.Yes, I am using autoLayout. I've added my code above but used an image instead. The code above works, but i'm not able to scroll. I'm also sure the approach I used isn't a good solution to change the position of the scroll view.